# Is it possible to get USER_ACCESS_TOKEN via graph API? how?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My main reason is to get PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN from one user via graph API. So do I have to get USER_ACCESS_TOKEN to do that? Also I wonder if there's a way to store PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN without expired.

Thanks.